# SQL Calculating full months

Tags: sql

I currently have an sql stored procedure which closes open tickets automatically after 6 months. Something like the following

```
UPDATE TABLE.TICKETS
SET STATUS = 'Closed'
WHERE DateAdd(MM,6,OPENED_DATE) < GETDATE()
```

This sets the status to closed whenever the opened_date was exactly 6 months ago or more.

What I need it to do is for it to calculate full months. For example

If the opened date is 05/05/2010, I don't want it to close at 05/11/2010 which it currently does (exactly 6 months - I now want it to close at the END of the month which is 6 months away. i.e the 05/05/2010 ticket would close on 01/12/2010. A ticket lodged on 15/05/2010 would also close on 01/12/2010.

Can anyone advise on the best way to do this? My mind is drawing a blank :(. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
UPDATE TABLE.TICKETS
SET STATUS = 'Closed'
WHERE OPENED_DATE < dateadd(mm, -6, GETDATE() - day(getdate) + 1)
```

The `day()` function returns the day of the month, so the expression `GETDATE() - day(getdate) + 1` returns the first day of the current month.  The rest subtracts six months and compares that to the `OPENED_DATE`.

Note that I switched the logic from the column to the "constant".  This allows SQL Server to use an index on `OPENED_DATE` if one is available (the technical term for this is "sargability").

Answer (score 0):

Check the last day of the month of the OPEN_DATE against today:

```
UPDATE TABLE.TICKETS
SET STATUS = 'Closed'
WHERE DateAdd(MM,6,DATEDIFF(m,0,OPENED_DATE)+1,0))) < GETDATE()
```